# How to optimize this query , it is taking time 40 minuts in execution?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from non_bidders_report_view
where applicant_category_id =1314 
and applicant_status_id not in(10,11) 
and partner_id = 4 
and  applicant_status_id <> 6 
and  applicant_id not in (
                          Select apb.applicant_id 
                          from applicant_property_bids apb 
                          inner join applicants a on
                          a.applicant_id=apb.applicant_id 
        where to_date(apb.bid_Date) >= to_date('30/4/2012','dd/mm/yyyy') 
        and to_date(apb.bid_Date) <= to_date('30/4/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') 
        and a.partner_id = 4 group by apb.applicant_Id  
        union 
        select aba.applicant_Id from Archive_Bid_Applicants aba 
        inner join applicants a on a.applicant_id=aba.applicant_id  
        where to_date(aba.bid_Date) >= to_date('30/4/2012','dd/mm/yyyy') 
        and to_date(aba.bid_Date) <= to_date('30/4/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') 
        and a.partner_id = 4 group by aba.applicant_Id 
        );
```

Comment: Need table schema, indexes, explain plan, etc.

Comment: Rather than `applicant_id not in ()`, use a `not exists` construction, should be quicker. Or use a `JOIN` construction, may be faster still.

Comment: @ HoneyBadger, Thank you sir, But 'not exists' is not working.

Comment: @AnandYadav Not working in what sense?

Comment: Anyone who is giving you any info without seeing trace files or index information is simply going on best practices. Trace the query and see where the hangs are.

Comment: @mmmmmpie Generally I agree. But in this particular query I noticed two `group by` sections and then these sections `union`-ed. All these steps were not necessary. After obvious corrections query finishes in 5 secs according to OP's words.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
select * from non_bidders_report_view nb
  where applicant_category_id = 1314 and partner_id = 4
    and applicant_status_id not in (6, 10, 11)  
    and not exists (
      select 1 from applicant_property_bids abp 
        join applicants a on a.applicant_id=abp.applicant_id and a.partner_id=4
          and abp.bid_Date between date '2012-04-30' and date '2015-04-30'
        where abp.applicant_id = nb.applicant_id )
    and not exists (
      select 1 from archive_bid_applicants aba 
        join applicants a on a.applicant_id=aba.applicant_id and a.partner_id=4
          and aba.bid_Date between date '2012-04-30' and date '2015-04-30'
        where aba.applicant_id = nb.applicant_id )
```

The idea is to get rid of `group by` and `union` which seems to be unnecesary here and change `not in` to `not exists`.

Alternative solution:

```
select * from non_bidders_report_view nb
  where applicant_category_id = 1314 and partner_id = 4
    and applicant_status_id not in (6, 10, 11)  
    and not exists (
      select 1 from (
          select applicant_id, bid_date from applicant_property_bids
          union all
          select applicant_id, bid_date from archive_bid_applicants
          ) ab 
        join applicants a on a.applicant_id=ab.applicant_id and a.partner_id=4
          and ab.bid_Date between date '2012-04-30' and date '2015-04-30'
        where ab.applicant_id = nb.applicant_id )
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - which query you did you choose and how long it runs now?

Comment: @ Ponder Stibbons ,last one i have select , it takes only 5 sec in execution,

Answer (score 0):

If you have millions of data then create index on primary key. It will increase your performance. Indexes helps to speed up data retrieval. Create index on all 3 tables.

Comment: thank you for quick response but sir index already created on 3 tables.

Comment: instead of using **group by apb.applicant_Id **. use **select distinct apb.applicant_id **.

Comment: You can also use Explain plan feature of Sql Developer to optimize your query.

Comment: Hi Anand, Got any success?

Comment: How you achieved and how much time it is taking now?